# Выполняется код, не входящий в условие

Tags: python

Код:

```
        db = pymysql.connect(host=db_host, user=db_user, password=db_password, db=db_name, charset=db_charset, cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM {table1} WHERE intid != 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1".format(table1=db_table1))
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM {table1} WHERE user_id = {user_id} ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1".format(table1=db_table1, user_id=user_id))
        rows2 = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM {table1}".format(table1=db_table1))
        rows3 = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM {table2}".format(table2=db_table2))
        sum0 = cursor.fetchall()
        counts = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM {table1} WHERE intid != 0".format(table1=db_table1))

        elif text[0].lower() == '!статус':
            if len(text) == 1:
                api.messages.send(peer_id=peer_id, message='Используйте: !статус <№ чека>')
            else:
                status_sign = hashlib.md5(str(merchant_id + merchant_secret).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
                status_link = 'http://www.free-kassa.ru/api.php?merchant_id=' + merchant_id + '&s=' + status_sign + '&intid=' + text[1] + '&action=check_order_status'
                resp_status = requests.get(status_link)
                parsed_status = xmltodict.parse(resp_status.content)
                if parsed_status['root']['desc'] == 'too fast, wait 10sec until next request':
                    api.messages.send(peer_id=peer_id,
                                      message=status_wait)
                elif parsed_status['root']['desc'] == 'Order not found':
                    api.messages.send(peer_id=peer_id,
                                      message=status_notfound)
                for row3 in rows3:
                    if text[1] in str(row3['intid']):
                        api.messages.send(peer_id=peer_id, message='test')
                if parsed_status['root']['status'] == 'completed':
                    api.messages.send(peer_id=peer_id,
                                      message=status_done.format(number=text[1],
                                                                 sum=parsed_status['root']['amount'],
                                                                 email=parsed_status['root']['email'],
                                                                 date=parsed_status['root']['date']))
                    for row in rows2:
                        cursor.execute("UPDATE {table1} SET intid = {intid} WHERE id = {id} AND user_id = {user_id}".format(table1=db_table1, intid=text[1], id=row['id'], user_id=user_id))
                        db.commit()
                else:
                    api.messages.send(peer_id=peer_id,
                                      message=status_dont.format(number=text[1],
                                                                 sum=parsed_status['root']['amount'],
                                                                 email=parsed_status['root']['email'],
                                                                 date=parsed_status['root']['date']))
```

После условия

```
if text[1] in str(row3['intid']): 
api.messages.send(peer_id=peer_id, message='test')
```

следующий код всё равно выполняется.
Нужно чтобы он не выполнялся, как это реализовать?

Comment: Переместить код ниже под условие `else`?

Comment: Не помогло.....

Comment: Ну, если я правильно понял, создайте булеву переменную и если проверка нужного условия истинна, то задайте этой переменной значение True. А следующий код выполняйте только если эта переменная равна False. Честно говоря не очень понятно, что именно вы хотите сделать

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы если в таблице есть intid который указал пользователь, то ему отправилось сообщение 'Данный товар уже выдан'.